# UITableViewCells change after scrolling down then back up

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView where when I scroll down and back up, the values are changing in the UILabels of cells. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I am using custom UITableViewCells that I have subclassed myself.

This is what my code looks like minus entering all of the values into the labels as I think the error is not there but in the way I declare the tableview delegate methods or something like that.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (sortedItemsArray == nil) {
        return 0;
    } else
        return [sortedItemsArray count];
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomallCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomallCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    if ([sortedItemsArray count] > 0) {
        currentallDictionary = [sortedItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        NSNumber *tempDU = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"DU"];
        NSInteger myInteger = [tempDU integerValue];
        
        if (myInteger == 0) {

//            NSLog(@"%@", currentallDictionary);
            //assign vals to labels

            NSString *areaString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"area"];
            if ((NSNull *) areaString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.areaLabel.text = areaString;
            } else {
                cell.areaLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            

            NSString *stageString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"stage"];
            if ((NSNull *) stageString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.stageLabel.text = stageString;
            } else {
                cell.stageLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            

            NSString *floorLabelString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"floorNo"];
            if ((NSNull *) floorLabelString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.floorLabel.text = floorLabelString;
            } else  {
                cell.floorLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            

            NSString *floorDescLabelString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"floorDesc"];
            if ((NSNull *) floorDescLabelString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.floorDescLabel.text = floorDescLabelString;
            } else  {
                cell.floorDescLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            
            
            
//Buttons
            tDxStateAString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tDxStateA"];
            tDxStateBString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tDxStateB"];
            tHasDxString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tHasDx"];
            
            if ([tHasDxString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
                tDxQtyString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tDxQty"];
                if ((NSNull *) tDxQtyString != [NSNull null]) {
                    cell.quantityALabel.text = tDxQtyString;
                    
                    
                    if (([tDxStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tDxStateBString isEqualToString:@"W"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOn.png"];
                        [cell.DxfitButtonImage setImage:checkedOnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    } else if (([tDxStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tDxStateBString isEqualToString:@"R"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnDisabledImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOnDisabled.png"];
                        [cell.DxfitButtonImage setImage:checkedOnDisabledImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }else {
                        UIImage *checkedOffImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOff.png"];
                        [cell.DxfitButtonImage setImage:checkedOffImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        cell.DxfitButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    cell.quantityALabel.text = @" ";
                    cell.DxfitButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                }
            }

            tStateAString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tStateA"];
            tStateBString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tStateB"];
            tHasInsString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tHasIns"];
            if ([tHasInsString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
                
                tInsQtyString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tInsQty"];
                if ((NSNull *) tInsQtyString != [NSNull null]) {
                    cell.quantityBLabel.text = tInsQtyString;
                    
                    if (([tStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tStateBString isEqualToString:@"W"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOn.png"];
                        [cell.allButtonImage setImage:checkedOnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    } else if (([tStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tStateBString isEqualToString:@"R"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnDisabledImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOnDisabled.png"];
                        [cell.allButtonImage setImage:checkedOnDisabledImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    } else {
                        UIImage *checkedOffImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOff.png"];
                        [cell.allButtonImage setImage:checkedOffImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                } else {
                    cell.quantityBLabel.text = @" ";
                    cell.allButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                }
            }
            
            
            
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

How can I stop the repetition of cells?

Comment: It looks fine, you take cell from reusable deque, and if this cell is not present here, create new. 
How do you configure your cell?

Comment: I guess the problem is the code you haven't shown, where you are assigning from sortedArray to you labels.

Comment: You can try to implement prepareForReuse method in your subclass and reset labels values. It may help to debug.

Comment: @Alex I have updated my code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomInstallCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomInstallCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *lbl_name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 280, 25)];
            lbl_name.tag = 1000;
            [lbl_name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f]];
            lbl_name.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
            lbl_name.numberOfLines = 0;
            [lbl_name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [lbl_name sizeToFit];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_name];
     //Create all your Labels here and set the tag
    }
    //Access your lbl by the tag here
    UILabel *lbl_name = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
    [lbl_name setText:[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    return cell;
}
```

Try like this.. Then no need check array has element in cellForRowAtIndexPath: if it have element then only the loop come here. I hope it will be helpful to you

Comment: What is this 'tag-magic'? why you just don't using property in subclass for this label?

Answer (score 0):

At the place you "fill in all the labels here", I'm not sure if what do you want to achieve.

If in your custom cell you have a lot of UILabel to fill using `sortedItemsArray`, then in the 
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` 
you should not return the `[sortedItemsArray count]`.

If there's one UILabel in your custom cell and you try to fill the label using `sortedItemsArray` based on the index, then all you need to do is

> cell.yourCustomLabel = sortedItemsArray[indexPath.row];

If your case is none of above, please attach more code to elaborate.

Comment: I have updated my code showing how I allocate data to my labels and buttons of my subclassed tableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

if you have subclassed uitableview cell  make sure you gave the "CellIdentifier" inside the atttrib utes inspector of your Custom cell  xib. and change your cell for row at indexpath like this

static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"cell";

```
CustomInstallCell * cell = (CustomInstallCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomInstallCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController work with reusable cells. The controller creates a limited number of cells and scrolls simply overwrites the contents. This can lead to duplication of certain properties in the cells. To avoid duplication, you can use the method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` of UITableViewDelegate. In this method, check out what is duplicated or incorrect and set it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` reuse cell when scroll table view,cells are reused based on `CellIdentifier`,in table view we create the new views only  `cell==nil` other wise we reuse cell in table view,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomInstallCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomInstallCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if ([sortedItemsArray count] > 0) {

          UIView *view=[CustomInstallCell viewWithTag:your view tag];
      //view is sub view of CustomInstallCell

        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure what yourviewtag is but i am investigating thanks for your reasponse I have not forgotten about this question/

Comment: I have updated my code showing how I am setting my label and buttons values

Comment: i am confused in your code you try another way to use cells,NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%i",indexPath.row]; but it not efficiency in ios

Comment: I cannot see the part your talking about? I am 98% certan that the cellIdentifier code is exaclty the same as before its the part inside sortedItemsarry count thats new. However there is a small chance I changed it trying to get something to work.. however I still have the exact same issue where the cells change when i scroll back up

Comment: y u use UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle ? your CustomInstallCell design static or dynamic ?

Comment: what do you mean by static and dynamic. The labels and buttons are placed and do not move.. so they are static, the values and weather I show say a label or a button is dynamic dependat on the values from the array.

Comment: also I have just changed to UITableViewCellStyleDefault it was a typo.

Comment: pls check assign vals to labels part in your code,the validation not correct,hide unused lable and buttons in u r code  if ([tHasDxString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
            
            cell.allButtonImage.hidden=YES;
            cell.DxfitButtonImage.hidden=NO;
            cell.quantityALabel.hidden=NO;
        }
        tHasInsString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tHasIns"];
        if ([tHasInsString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
            
            cell.allButtonImage.hidden=NO;
            cell.DxfitButtonImage.hidden=YES;
            cell.quantityALabel.hidden=YES;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier;        
    if(IPAD)
        CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EditCell_ipad%d",indexPath.row];
    else
        CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EditCell_iphone%d",indexPath.row];


     CustomallCell *cell=(CustomallCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomallCell_TablviewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        if(IPAD)
        cell = (CustomallCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        else
        cell = (CustomallCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:1];
    }
```

I am using unique Idetifier for each cell, so there is no chance to repeat/overwrite data cell problem.Like after scrolling the previous status of cell is changed that will not happen with this code

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];
```

Comment: just replace this single line in your code in   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{