# SubClass of UITableViewCell not behaving correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have subclassed a `UITableViewCell` and am getting a very good performance boost from doing so, However I have encountered a problem. I notice when I scroll down then back up my `tableviewcells` are changing.

At a close inspection I think the values from the bottom are being added in at the top of the `tableview` as I scroll up. However this is the first time I have ever subclassed a `UITableViewCell` so I am having some difficulty.

Anyway I would like to show you my `tableviewdelegate` method where I am adding the custom cells to the tableview using **`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`**.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomallCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomallCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    if ([sortedItemsArray count] > 0) {
        currentallDictionary = [sortedItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        NSNumber *tempDU = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"DU"];
        NSInteger myInteger = [tempDU integerValue];
        
        if (myInteger == 0) {

            //NSLog(@"%@", currentallDictionary);
            //assign vals to labels

            NSString *areaString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"area"];
            if ((NSNull *) areaString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.areaLabel.text = areaString;
            } else {
                cell.areaLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            

            NSString *stageString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"stage"];
            if ((NSNull *) stageString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.stageLabel.text = stageString;
            } else {
                cell.stageLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            

            NSString *floorLabelString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"floorNo"];
            if ((NSNull *) floorLabelString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.floorLabel.text = floorLabelString;
            } else  {
                cell.floorLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            

            NSString *floorDescLabelString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"floorDesc"];
            if ((NSNull *) floorDescLabelString != [NSNull null]) {
                cell.floorDescLabel.text = floorDescLabelString;
            } else  {
                cell.floorDescLabel.text = @" ";
            }  
            
//Buttons
            tDxStateAString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tDxStateA"];
            tDxStateBString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tDxStateB"];
            tHasDxString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tHasDx"];
            
            if ([tHasDxString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
                tDxQtyString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tDxQty"];
                if ((NSNull *) tDxQtyString != [NSNull null]) {
                    cell.quantityALabel.text = tDxQtyString;
                    
                    
                    if (([tDxStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tDxStateBString isEqualToString:@"W"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOn.png"];
                        [cell.DxfitButtonImage setImage:checkedOnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    } else if (([tDxStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tDxStateBString isEqualToString:@"R"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnDisabledImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOnDisabled.png"];
                        [cell.DxfitButtonImage setImage:checkedOnDisabledImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }else {
                        UIImage *checkedOffImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOff.png"];
                        [cell.DxfitButtonImage setImage:checkedOffImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        cell.DxfitButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    cell.quantityALabel.text = @" ";
                    cell.DxfitButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                }
            }

            tStateAString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tStateA"];
            tStateBString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tStateB"];
            tHasInsString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tHasIns"];
            if ([tHasInsString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
                
                tInsQtyString = [currentallDictionary objectForKey:@"tInsQty"];
                if ((NSNull *) tInsQtyString != [NSNull null]) {
                    cell.quantityBLabel.text = tInsQtyString;
                    
                    if (([tStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tStateBString isEqualToString:@"W"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOn.png"];
                        [cell.allButtonImage setImage:checkedOnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    } else if (([tStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tStateBString isEqualToString:@"R"])) {
                        UIImage *checkedOnDisabledImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOnDisabled.png"];
                        [cell.allButtonImage setImage:checkedOnDisabledImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    } else {
                        UIImage *checkedOffImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOff.png"];
                        [cell.allButtonImage setImage:checkedOffImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                } else {
                    cell.quantityBLabel.text = @" ";
                    cell.allButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                }
            }
            
            
            
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

### Update

I have added this method to my custom UITableViewCell class however although the problem isn't as bad I find if I hold my finger down on the screen and zoom it up and down without letting go it seems to jiggle the cells around and different values are appearing like before but kind of differently. Maybe this is a logic problem with my code?

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    areaLabel = nil;
    stageLabel = nil;
    floorLabel = nil;
    floorDescLabel = nil;
    // etc....

    [self didTransitionToState:UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCells change after scrolling down then back up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679377/uitableviewcells-change-after-scrolling-down-then-back-up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is common, and it's related with the fact that UITableView is reusing your cells.

When you call dequeue cell, you are taking cells that disappear from the top and using them back on the bottom.

You need to "clean" a cell before reusing it.

You can remove everything on it after dequeuing it:

```
    CustomallCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomallCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

//Remove or clean subviews here
```

Or, implement this method:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
```

In the UITableViewCell, to clean the cell. That method will be called when the cell is going to be reused.

Comment: so something like this should work [cell removeFromSuperview]; sorry if this is incorrect I havent done this before.. ill continue looking otherwise.

Comment: No, you need to clean the values that are inside the cell, for example, imagine that you have a uilabel with a value, when you reuse that cell the label will have the previous value, so you need to set it to nil before using it again

Comment: okay cool. I understand what your saying now. I will have more of a read arround then attempt it myself thanks! Ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: You're welcome, I recommend you to take a look at the UItableView Programming guide by Apple. Please accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: I have just updated my question. I implemented prepareForReuse but I am still getting a problem with the different values but its kind of different I am woundering if it is a logic problem that I am on now. Could you tell me if the code I made is correct? that way I know if I should move on or keep trying this.

Comment: IT's almost correct. Set the text of the values to nil, not the variables. For example. myLabel.text = nil, etc.

Comment: I have just been testing some more and its still definatly happening. its not the logic the cells are jumping but only if i run my finger up and down say several times.. then after the fourth or fifth time the bottom values jump up into the top cells.

Comment: did u try this? Set the text of the values to nil, not the variables. For example. myLabel.text = nil, etc.

Comment: okay this has definatly worked for the labels.. however I have two UIButtons I am showing and that I am declaring as nil in prepareForReuse are still changing.. I am guessing I have done it wrong for them.. they look like this in prepareForReuse "dfitButtonImage = nil;
    insButtonImage = nil;"

Comment: Same as before, you are setting the whole variable to nil. Set the parasmeters on it to nil, for example [allButtonImage setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: ahhhhh, it worked I was trying everything like reloadviews and stuff like that.. didnt think of setImage:nil :) thanks very much for your awesom help.. now to go and do this to the 4 other subclassed tableviewcells in the other parts of my app LOL thanks