# Labels in custom TableView cells disappearing after scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have dynamically tableView with custom cell. CustomCell .h file looks like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uslugaName;  //I set retain doesn't work too
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *howMuchPayLbl;
```

My CellForRowAtIndexPathMethod:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    myCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


     /*
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[myCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    */

    if (indexPath.row !=15) {

    cell.uslugaName.text =serviceNameArr[indexPath.row];

    //окрашиваем ячейку в зависимости от активности услуги
    if ([uslugaIsActiveArr[indexPath.row]  isEqual: @"1"]) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.howMuchPayLbl.enabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.howMuchPayLbl.enabled = NO;
    }

   if (![amountTmpArr[indexPath.row]  isEqual: @"0"])
       cell.howMuchPayLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Оплачиваю: %@ KZT", amountTmpArr[indexPath.row]];
}
    else {
        cell.uslugaName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System Bold" size:16];
        cell.uslugaName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ОБЩАЯ СУММА ОПЛАТЫ: %@", fullAmount];
        cell.howMuchPayLbl.hidden = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I want that last row different than others ( for this purpose this:

> if (indexPath.row !=15)

). Problem is - when scrolling cell.howMuchPayLb disappear. If delete special code for last row - all works ok, why this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code has an `if else` statement where one branch can set `cell.howMuchPayLbl.hidden = YES;` but the other branch does not set `cell.howMuchPayLbl.hidden = NO;`. So, once the label is hidden it will never be un-hidden. When the cell with the hidden label is reused the label remains hidden.

Add `cell.howMuchPayLbl.hidden = NO;` (and any other 'inverse' configuration required) to your `if` statement.

Comment: huff.. Wasted almost a day and you saved another couple of days

Answer (score 0):

Refer This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679377/uitableviewcells-change-after-scrolling-down-then-back-up/23800339#23800339) will help you..
Its because of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will not recognize the cell-identifire with same name.So you can use unique cell identifire like Cell1,Cell2...for each row..