# Label disappear when table is reloaded / scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, label

I have a `UITableview` with two `UILabels` like in the chat. When the visible `UITableview` is filled and when I add extra cells, my `UILabel`s get disappeared.

There are may other `UILabels` which is visible. Only those 2 chat `UILabels` is hidden. Can anyone suggest me the possible solution?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
ChatScreenViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
index = indexPath.row + 1;
indexx = indexPath;


cell.ChatLabel1.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
cell.ChatLabel1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.ChatLabel2.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
cell.ChatLabel2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.ImageviewLabel1.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
cell.ImageviewLabel1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.ImageviewLabel2.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
cell.ImageviewLabel2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.ImageviewLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];



if([Replychat[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"bot"] != NULL)
{

    cell.ChatLabel1.text = [Replychat[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"bot"];
    cell.ChatLabel2.hidden = YES;
    cell.ImageviewLabel2.hidden = YES;

    cell.TimeLabel1.text = TimeArray[indexPath.row];
}
else
{

    cell.ChatLabel2.text = [Replychat[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"User"];
    cell.ChatLabel1.hidden = YES;
    cell.ImageviewLabel1.hidden = YES;
    cell.TimeLabel2.text = TimeArray[indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Add you code work. and screen shot also.

Comment: the problem is cell reusability.

Comment: @meowsush you need to update your question with cellForRowAtIndexPath code and a rough guess is you may not have reloaded your UITableview after updating the array

Comment: I have added my cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: I  have updated. my problem is that the label is ok till the visible tableview when i add more values in it its getting appearing and disappearing

Answer (score 1):

[Labels in custom TableView cells disappearing after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810122/labels-in-custom-tableview-cells-disappearing-after-scrolling?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My code has an if else statement where one branch can set cell.ChatLabel2.hidden = YES; but the other branch does not set cell.ChatLabel2.hidden = NO;. So, once the label is hidden it will never be un-hidden. When the cell with the hidden label is reused the label remains hidden.

Add cell.ChatLabel2.hidden = NO; (and any other 'inverse' configuration required) to your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   //....
    cell.ImageviewLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   // because tableview reuse uitableviewcell, so you must reset hidden status for lable
    cell.ChatLabel2.hidden = NO;
    cell.ChatLabel1.hidden = NO;

   if([Replychat[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"bot"] != NULL)
   //....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
  {

ChatScreenViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:@"ChatCell"];
```

}

index = indexPath.row + 1;

indexx = indexPath;

cell.ChatLabel1.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

cell.ChatLabel1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.ChatLabel2.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

cell.ChatLabel2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.ImageviewLabel1.layer.cornerRadius = 20;

cell.ImageviewLabel1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.ImageviewLabel2.layer.cornerRadius = 20;

cell.ImageviewLabel2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.ImageviewLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

if([Replychat[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"bot"] != NULL)
{

cell.ChatLabel1.hidden = NO;

cell.ChatLabel1.text = [Replychat[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"bot"];

cell.ChatLabel2.hidden = YES;

cell.ImageviewLabel2.hidden = YES;

cell.TimeLabel1.text = TimeArray[indexPath.row];

}

else{

cell.ChatLabel2.hidden = NO;

cell.ChatLabel2.text = [Replychat[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"User"];

cell.ChatLabel1.hidden = YES;

cell.ImageviewLabel1.hidden = YES;

cell.TimeLabel2.text = TimeArray[indexPath.row];

}

return cell;

}